# Как отменить обновление сохраненного варианта кода в Gist при сохранении изменений в редакторе?

Tags: github, sublime-text-3

Написал код - прям через редактор (sublime text) залил его на Gist. Дальше при каждом сохранении изменений в редакторе - меняется и код, залитый на gist.
Можно ли отменить синхронизацию, чтобы код можно было сохранить на gist только один раз и дальше при редактировании в sublime он не менялся?

Comment: Вне зависимости от Вашей проблемы, (которую, думаю, можно отладить и в Gist), я не рекомендовал бы пользоваться пакетом [**Gist**](https://github.com/condemil/Gist), потому что он давно не обновлялся, — разработчик, видимо, отошёл от проекта. Попробуйте [**HaoGist**](https://github.com/xjsender/HaoGist). Потестировал этот пакет: всё ([**почти**](https://github.com/bgreenlee/sublime-github/issues/105)) работает, Ваша проблема не воспроизводится. Спасибо.

Comment: Ок, попробую. Спасибо за совет